# Convolution neural networks -- all feature maps are black(pixel value is 0)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am doing a project that maps trained CNNs on Zynq Soc. I trained a Lenet in tensorflow and extracted weights and biases. As far as I observed, the value of weights are all close to 0, almost none of them larger than 1. But the input data of lenet is gray scale image and the pixel value is from 0 to 255.

When I tried to do 2-D convolution between input image and kernel (trained weights), the output feature maps are all black image since the convolution result are all close to 0. Even takes Relu layer into account. But as shown in this picture below, the value of weight in the kernel and feature maps should be a value between 0 to 255 according to the brightness.

I just wonder why I got black(0 pixel value) feature maps?

[image]

Comment: are you sure values in figure are close to 255? is it possible the brightness was scaled? what happens if you plot **your** filters and responses and scale their values to [0..256]?

Answer (score 0):

The inputs are normalized before doing a convolution and the feature maps created are normalized as well to create the images. To create similar images you will have to find out how the inputs were normalized in the network that created the weights you are using and normalize your inputs in the same way, then do min-max normalization on the feature map and get it into 0-255 range.